# Image width does not change proportionally in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

When I try to change the height of an image's parent div dynamically, the width changes proportionally in Chrome. However, this expected behavior is not working in Safari.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="imagee-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<button id="2">Increase height</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

**JS (to test dynamically increasing height)**

```
$("#2").click(function() {
  $("div").css("height", "+=5");

});
```

Here's a fiddle to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/MNL29/53/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works properly in Firefox too. So in Safari, does the image height track the container height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also updating to change the image size instead of the container size works. So, instead of having the image stretch to fill the div size (which the width of the div isn't changing so it makes some sense that the width of the image wouldn't change either), you can change the image size and have the div stretch to contain the image, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/jy8xwhj3/

```js
$("#2").click(function() {
  $(".image-wrapper img").css("height", "+=5");
});
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

.image-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="2">Increase height</button>

<div class="content">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unable to run your snippet. There's an error just below it.

Comment: Updated with jQuery included from the sidebar.

Comment: But what if you actually need to change the height of the container? The problem is that even Safari, if you change any css concerning the img in devtools after this size change, it rerenders the content to the expected outcome. So it really is Safari's bug, that it cannot do it immed.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works like this:

```js
$("#2").click(function() {
  $("div").css("height", "+=5");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg"
    /><img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg"
    /><img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg"
    /><img src="http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bird-photography-feeders.jpg" />
    <br />
    <button id="2">Increase height</button>
</div>
```

Or see in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6e6zpetd/

Answer (score 0):

For those who, same as me, cannot change the image height directly (as in accepted answer) and have to change the height of the container, there is a solution. Not and elegant one, but it works.

Safari actually knows how to render it correctly, it just does not "realize" when it should rerender it. After the height modification, if you change any css property that potentially can affect the element's box, it forces a render and it takes the new height into an account.

Just create a dummy class with for example max-width:100% and each time the height is updated, toggle the class on or off (easily done with jQuery .toggleClass). Content gets rerendered, everyone is happy.

If someone know the mechanism / issue behind it, I am curious.